# How do I create a local project for the PubSub emulator?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I want to create a local project so I can create topics for it and send messages as part of testing. How do I do this? I didn't see anything in the [REST documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/) for PubSub - I have tried omitting the project name from the URL when creating topics but that hasn't worked.

Comment: Have you reviewed the docs on using the [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator)?

Comment: Yep - I have been able to get it working and I know it is listening to the port correctly (as it spews out a bunch of stuff about my requests being wrong when I submit them).

Comment: @Andrew Did you figure this out? Can you post the code you use to connect to the emulator? It simply hangs for me when I try to connect.

Comment: @Clay no, I gave up. The libraries for connecting to it in Java are all alpha and I had other issues on that side, not worth spending a ton of time fighting the code when it could be changed soon.

Comment: @Andrew I'm having the same issues with the Python libraries. They're just broken, from the best I can tell. At least it's cheap to use live PubSub for development.